# ViewModel , Fragment , liveData , Retrofit

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm facing a problem with display data in fragmentRecycler
I'm using retrofit to get json 
using viewModel and liveData to observe and survive from activity configurations 
but i don't know how to display these respondes as item's
in my Fragment recyclerView
this is my fragment onCreate Method code :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    voucherViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(voucherViewModel.class);
    model.getVoucher().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<Voucher>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Voucher> vouchers) {
            Log.e("on change", "onChanged: " );
            adapter = new homeRecycleViewAdapter(getContext(),vouchers );
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    });

}//end onCreate
```

my OnCreateView Method Code :-

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout, container, false);
    adapter = new homeRecycleViewAdapter(context);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerViewID);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //return inflated view
    return view;
}
```

so i hope to get help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use any views in onCreate() of fragment. Here the view are not created, So you might get errors.

Second of all, 
Let onCreteView only return the view which you are inflating.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout, container, false)
    return view;
}
```

Once the inflating is complete, you get the callback on onViewCreated. here you can access all the views like your recyclerview. Here they will be inflated.

```
@Override
void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeRecycleViewAdapter adapter = new homeRecycleViewAdapter(context, vouchers);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerViewID);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
```